# How to link to this to the database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have created a random string generator. What happens is that the user would click on a button and by using letters A and B it will construct a 3 letter string like these for example:

```
AAA
AAB
ABA
ABB
BAA
BAB
BBA
BBB
```

Now what I want is my random string generation to link with the "SessionId" column which is in the "Session" Table of my database where these strings will be stored in. What I want is the button to generate a string which is not in the database. For example look below (SessionId in Session Table):

```
Session Id

AAA
AAB
```

As these two sessions (string AAA and AAB) are in the database the generator should not display these two strings at all when clicking on the button and generating the strings as they are already in the database. Later on I want the genrated string to be stored in the database but at the moment I just want my generator to generate strings that are already in the database.

Does anyone know how to link this to my "Session Id" field in the "Session" Table and generate strings which are not in the database?

My code is in jsfiddle so you can see how the button works and the code used, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tskNK/) to see

Below is my php code I am using at moment. This php code will let me connect to database and all user to enter a courseId in the textbox, if courseId is in textbox then user can enter else it will display an alert. Below is code:

```
      <?php

              $username="xxxxxxxxxxx";
              $password="xxxxxx";
              $database="mobile_app";

              mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
              @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

              foreach (array('courseid') as $varname) {
                $courseid = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
              }

            ?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<p>Course ID: <input type="text" name="courseid" value="<?php echo $courseid; ?>" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
            </form>

            <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = "
                     SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
                     c.CourseName,
                     m.ModuleName
                     FROM Course c
                     INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
                     JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
                     WHERE
                     (c.CourseId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."')
                     ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
                     ";



    $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));
        mysql_close()

;
?>
```

updated php code below:

```
<?php

      $username=xxx";
      $password="xxx";
      $database="mobile_app";


      $is_there = true;

      $con = mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
      @mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Unable to select database");

while( $is_there ){
    $id = id_generator(); // your function to generate id;
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT SessionId FROM Session WHERE SessionId = '$id'" );
    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0 ) $is_there = false;
}




      foreach (array('courseid', 'sessionid') as $varname) {
        $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }

    ?>

    <h1>CREATING A SESSION</h1>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
         <p>Course ID: <input type="text" name="courseid" value="<?php echo $courseid; ?>" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
        </form>

        <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $query = "
                 SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
                 c.CourseName,
                 m.ModuleName
                 FROM Course c
                 INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
                 JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
                 WHERE
                 (c.CourseId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."')
                 ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
                 ";

    $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));
    mysql_close();
```

Comment: I'm sorry. My brain ran away. What are you trying to do? (explanation for dummies)

Comment: @MichaelSazonov ... it is the holiday season. My brain also tends to get loose this time of year.

Comment: Ok I have a database which contains a Session Table. Inside the Session Table is a Session Id. The SessionId stores in previous generated strings which have been selected. Now if a string like "AAA" is already in the database, then when the user generates a new string, it will never generate the string "AAA" as it is already taken (already stored in database). I need it working like this exactly.

Comment: The StackOverflow community would appreciate it if you changed your user name to something that we might have some chance of remembering (e.g. a real nickname rather than a machine generated one).  As it is now "user1096892", it is pseudo-anonymous and we have no chance of remembering you, any of your previous questions or context if our paths cross again.

Comment: I will sort out my nickname a bit later on :)

Comment: I am using MYSQL database by the way

Comment: @user1096892 what are you coding with? PHP?

Comment: at the mo I have connected to the database through php and I have made a query where it allows the user to type in a courseId in textbox and if courseId is in database, then allow user to enter else display alert, I will add my php code in my question in 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code on the server should be like:

```
$is_there = true;

$con = mysql_connect( address , user, pass );
mysql_select_db( DATABASE , $con );

while( $is_there ){
    $id = id_generator(); // your function to generate id;
    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id = '$id'" );
    if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) == 0 ) $is_there = false;
}
```

This will stop when generated id is not found in the DB.

```
<?php

              ...
              @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
              $courseid = "";
              while( $is_there ){
              $courseid = id_generator(); // your function to generate id;
              $query = "
                     SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, 
                     c.CourseName,
                     m.ModuleName
                     FROM Course c
                     INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
                     JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
                     WHERE
                     (c.CourseId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."')
                     ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId
                     ";

              if( mysql_num_rows( $result = mysql_query($query) ) == 0 ) $is_there = false;
              }
              mysql_close();
              echo "You generated code id: " . $courseid;

              ?>...
```

Comment: Hi i included my php code, do I need to add another query or can I include WHERE clause in my current query?

Comment: Just as jfriend00 said, it's better to generate the id on the server. I didn't see how exactly you make the query? Have you just forgot the mysql_query() or is there something else?

Comment: Hi no there is some more php where result = the mysql_query, this has just been displayed at bottom of my php code. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Is there a reason for `foreach(){...}`? As it seems, you require only one value delivered by "POST". Why not using `$courseid = ( $_POST['courseid'] ) ? $_POST['courseid'] : '';`? See my editings in the answer

Comment: I think it is because on other files I have numerous variables such as $courseId, $moduleId, $teacherId etc, but in this file  only have $courseId, should I change it to what you have suggested?

Comment: We should pass to chat with that.

Comment: by the way is the am I suppose to use id_generator() as my function or use "generateRandomString(strLength)" which I have called it to generate the function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5927/discussion-between-user1096892-and-michael-sazonov)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to generate a random session ID that is not already in your database, then you probably need to create a server method for generating a new session ID that creates an ID that is not in the database already and use an ajax call to retrieve that new session ID from the server.

If you try to get all the existing IDs into the client and then generate a new ID on the client, you will open yourself to race conditions that would allow clients to both have the same ID (because they were both making one around the same time).  This type of operation should be done on the server with appropriate locks to avoid race conditions.  How you do it on the server depends upon what database/server framework you are using.

Comment: Hi, problem is I know the theory but I really have no idea not to code it, I am still learning javascript and I havn't used php for 2 years, if you or somebody can provide an example code then I can try and modify it to match my spec. Greatly appreciate if this can be done

Comment: I am using MYSQL database by the way

Comment: That is a PHP, mySQL question (nothing to do with javascript) which is not my area.  Hopefully someone else can weight in to help.